# SQL Merge from staging table causing duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that is moving data between a staging table and several destination tables. There is one table where I'm trying to update two columns that identify when something was initially flagged and when it was last flagged.  The tables are defined like this

`MyStaging` table:

```
STAGING_ROW_ID*     FILE_DATETIME              IMPORT_ID       UPDATE_ID       COMPUTER_IP
    1              '2020-08-27 11:44:47.000'     1            100-1           192.168.100.1
    2              '2020-08-31 12:15:48.000'     1            100-1           192.168.100.1
    3              '2020-08-31 12:30:10.000'     1            100-2           192.168.100.2
```

`MyTable` table:

```
UPDATE_ID*    COMPUTER_IP*       FIRST_DATE_FLAGGED    LAST_DATE_FLAGGED     TOTAL_NUMBER
  100-1       192.168.100.1    2020-08-27 11:44:47.000  2020-08-31 12:15:48.000       2
  100-2       192.168.100.2    2020-08-31 12:30:10.000  2020-08-31 12:30:10.000       1
```

*Asterisks denote primary keys

During my merge, I'm trying to do this:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable mt 
USING (SELECT UPDATE_ID, COMPUTER_IP, FILE_DATETIME, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_NUMBER
       FROM dbo.MyStaging
       WHERE "IMPORT_ID" = @importID
       GROUP BY UPDATE_ID, COMPUTER_IP, FILE_DATETIME) ms ON mt.UPDATE_ID = ms.UPDATE_ID
                                                          AND mt.COMPUTER_IP = ms.COMPUTER_IP

WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE 
        SET
            mt.TOTAL_NUMBER = mt.TOTAL_NUMBER + ms.TOTAL_NUMBER, 
            mt.LAST_DATE_FLAGGED = CASE WHEN ms.FILE_DATETIME > mt.LAST_DATE_FLAGGED
                                           THEN ms.FILE_DATETIME 
                                           ELSE mt.LAST_DATE_FLAGGED 
                                   END

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (UPDATE_ID, COMPUTER_IP, FIRST_DATE_FLAGGED, LAST_DATE_FLAGGED, TOTAL_NUMBER)
    VALUES (ms.UPDATE_ID, ms.COMPUTER_IP, ms.FILE_DATETIME, ms.FILE_DATETIME, ms.TOTAL_NUMBER);
```

I know that this is not the right approach. I'm getting an error because the `FILE_DATETIME` column causes some duplicates. Since `UPDATE_ID` and `COMPUTER_IP` are a compound key in `MyTable` and it will have multiple entries for `FILE_DATETIME`, this is understandable.

My question is how would I change my merge to get these dates while still only getting the appropriate columns? In an update statement, I only need to update the `LAST_DATE_FLAGGED` column. In an insert, I just need the latest date to be both the first and last dates.

Comment: Requirement is not clear. You want to update `LAST_DATE_IDENTIFIED` but you are updating `LAST_DATE_FLAGGED`. In case of multiple which row should be taken into account for update ? and what is count(*) based on ?

Comment: Apologies, the column names end in "FLAGGED". Have edited it.

Comment: As I asked , in case of multiple which value to be updated to `LAST_DATE_FLAGGED` and count(*) for the compound key or including date ?

Comment: LAST_DATE_FLAGGED should be the latest date for that particular compound key.

Comment: Please read [MERGE with caution](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) - maybe there's more to your batch but there's definitely an issue if you aren't using the right locking/isolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correct, you can change the using clause to use `MAX` to get the latest date data,

```
MERGE INTO dbo.MyTable mt 
USING (SELECT UPDATE_ID, COMPUTER_IP, MAX(FILE_DATETIME) AS FILE_DATETIME, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_NUMBER
       FROM dbo.MyStaging
       WHERE "IMPORT_ID" = @importID
       GROUP BY UPDATE_ID, COMPUTER_IP) ms ON mt.UPDATE_ID = ms.UPDATE_ID
                                                          AND mt.COMPUTER_IP = ms.COMPUTER_IP

WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE 
        SET
            mt.TOTAL_NUMBER = mt.TOTAL_NUMBER + ms.TOTAL_NUMBER, 
            mt.LAST_DATE_FLAGGED = CASE WHEN ms.FILE_DATETIME > mt.LAST_DATE_FLAGGED
                                           THEN ms.FILE_DATETIME 
                                           ELSE mt.LAST_DATE_FLAGGED 
                                   END

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT (UPDATE_ID, COMPUTER_IP, FIRST_DATE_FLAGGED, LAST_DATE_FLAGGED, TOTAL_NUMBER)
    VALUES (ms.UPDATE_ID, ms.COMPUTER_IP, ms.FILE_DATETIME, ms.FILE_DATETIME, ms.TOTAL_NUMBER);
```